# Combining Different Relations in Prisma ORM

Tags: javascript, typescript, database-design, prisma

I am trying to make a create operation that includes different relations. Here is my schema:

```
// This is your Prisma schema file,
// learn more about it in the docs: https://pris.ly/d/prisma-schema

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mysql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}



enum UserType {
  STUDENT
  TEACHER
  ADMIN // "İdare"
}

model User {
  // Default schema for next-auth
  id            String   @unique @id @default(cuid())
  name          String
  image         String?
  

  
  @@map("users")

  // Custom
  type UserType
  studentData Student?
  teacherData Teacher?
  adminData Admin?

  TC String @db.Char(11) @unique // TC will be used like a password for any type of user.
}

model Student {
  id            String    @unique @id @default(cuid())
  schoolNumber String @db.Char(3) @unique

  class   Class @relation(fields: [classId], references: [id])
  classId String

  examResults ExamResult[]

  user   User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId String  @unique
}

model Class {
  id            String    @unique @id @default(cuid())
  level Int @db.SmallInt
  letter String @db.Char(1)
  students Student[]

  availableExams AvailableExamsOfClasses[]
}

enum TeacherField {
  MATH
  COMPUTER_SCIENCE

  PHYSICS
  CHEMISTRY
  BIOLOGY

  TURKISH
  ENGLISH
  DEUTSCH
  HISTORY
  GEOGRAPHY
  RELIGION

  PHYSICAL_EDUCATION
  MUSIC
  ART
}

model Teacher {
  id            String    @unique @id @default(cuid())
  field TeacherField
  exams Exam[]

  user   User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId String  @unique
}

enum AdminRole {
  PRINCIPAL // Müdür
  DEPUTY_PRINCIPAL // Müdür yardımcısı
  COMPUTER_SCIENCE_TEACHER // Bilgisayar bilimleri öğretmeni
  COUNSELOR // Rehber öğretmen
  
}

model Admin {
  id            String    @unique @id @default(cuid())
  role AdminRole

  user   User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId String  @unique
}

model Exam {
  id            String    @unique @id @default(cuid())
  
  createdBy   Teacher @relation(fields: [createdById], references: [id])
  createdById String

  availableClasses AvailableExamsOfClasses[]
  answers Json
  results  ExamResult[]
}

model AvailableExamsOfClasses {
  exam       Exam     @relation(fields: [examId], references: [id])
  examId     String
  class   Class @relation(fields: [classId], references: [id])
  classId String

  @@id([examId, classId])
}

model ExamResult {
  id            String    @unique @id @default(cuid())
  
  student   Student @relation(fields: [studentId], references: [id])
  studentId String
  
  exam   Exam @relation(fields: [examId], references: [id])
  examId String

  result Json
}
```

I couldn't figure out the syntax i need for creating an exam using Prisma client.

- createdBy is the teacher that created the exam.
- availableClasses is the list of classes that can access this exam
- answers are obviously answers of exam (like `{questionNumber: 1, answer: "A"}`)
- results is an array of exam results

I tried this code but it throws errors:

```
    const teacher1 = await prisma.user.findUnique({
        where: {
            TC: "11111111114",
        },
    });
    const _9D = await prisma.class.findFirst({
        where: {
            letter: "D",
            level: 9,
        },
    });
    const exam = await prisma.exam.create({
        data: {
            createdBy: teacher1,
            answers: [
                { questionNumber: 1, answer: "E" },
                { questionNumber: 2, answer: "B" },
            ],
            results: [],
            availableClasses: [_9D],
        },
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with the help of these two links (especially the second one):

- [Prisma Client Reference (connect)](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#connect)
- [Working with many-to-many-relations](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/database/troubleshooting-orm/help-articles/working-with-many-to-many-relations)

I updated many-to-many relation between availableExams of class model and availableClasses of exam model according to second link. So this is the new schema now:

```
// This is your Prisma schema file,
// learn more about it in the docs: https://pris.ly/d/prisma-schema

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mysql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

// Default schema for next-auth
// model Account {
//   id                String  @id @default(cuid())
//   userId            String  @map("user_id")
//   type              String
//   provider          String
//   providerAccountId String  @map("provider_account_id")
//   refresh_token     String?
//   access_token      String?
//   expires_at        Int?
//   token_type        String?
//   scope             String?
//   id_token          String?
//   session_state     String?
//   user User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
//   @@unique([provider, providerAccountId])
//   @@map("accounts")
// }

// Default schema for next-auth
// model Session {
//   id           String   @id @default(cuid())
//   sessionToken String   @unique @map("session_token")
//   userId       String   @map("user_id")
//   expires      DateTime
//   user         User     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
//   @@map("sessions")
// }


enum UserType {
  STUDENT
  TEACHER
  ADMIN // "İdare"
}

model User {
  // Default schema for next-auth
  id            String   @unique @id @default(cuid())
  name          String
  image         String?
  

  // In default schema but we will not use
  // email         String?   @unique
  // emailVerified DateTime? @map("email_verified_at")
  // password      String?
  // accounts      Account[]
  // sessions      Session[]
  
  @@map("users")

  // Custom
  type UserType
  studentData Student?
  teacherData Teacher?
  adminData Admin?

  TC String @db.Char(11) @unique // TC will be used like a password for any type of user.
}

model Student {
  id            String    @unique @id @default(cuid())
  schoolNumber String @db.Char(3) @unique

  class   Class @relation(fields: [classId], references: [id])
  classId String

  examResults ExamResult[]

  user   User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId String  @unique
}

model Class {
  id            String    @unique @id @default(cuid())
  level Int @db.SmallInt
  letter String @db.Char(1)
  students Student[]
  availableExams Exam[]
}

enum TeacherField {
  MATH
  COMPUTER_SCIENCE

  PHYSICS
  CHEMISTRY
  BIOLOGY

  TURKISH
  ENGLISH
  DEUTSCH
  HISTORY
  GEOGRAPHY
  RELIGION

  PHYSICAL_EDUCATION
  MUSIC
  ART
}

model Teacher {
  id            String    @unique @id @default(cuid())
  field TeacherField
  exams Exam[]

  user   User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId String  @unique
}

enum AdminRole {
  PRINCIPAL // Müdür
  DEPUTY_PRINCIPAL // Müdür yardımcısı
  COMPUTER_SCIENCE_TEACHER // Bilgisayar bilimleri öğretmeni
  COUNSELOR // Rehber öğretmen
  
}

model Admin {
  id            String    @unique @id @default(cuid())
  role AdminRole

  user   User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId String  @unique
}

model Exam {
  id            String    @unique @id @default(cuid())
  
  createdBy   Teacher @relation(fields: [createdById], references: [id])
  createdById String

  availableClasses Class[]
  answers Json
  results  ExamResult[]
}


model ExamResult {
  id            String    @unique @id @default(cuid())
  
  student   Student @relation(fields: [studentId], references: [id])
  studentId String
  
  exam   Exam @relation(fields: [examId], references: [id])
  examId String

  result Json
}
```

And I used this syntax for adding a new exam:

```
const _9D = await prisma.class.findFirst({
        where: {
            letter: "D",
            level: 9,
        },
    });
    const teacher1 = await prisma.user.findUnique({
        where: { TC: "11111111114" },
    });
    const exam = await prisma.exam.create({
        data: {
            createdBy: {
                connect: { id: teacher1.teacherData.id },
            },
            availableClasses: {
                connect: { id: _9D.id },
            },
            answers: [],
        }
    });
```

Wish it helps developers with a similar problem :)